# Change background colour of a label when input[type='radio'] is checked

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change background-color of a label when input[type='radio'] is checked. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="type">
  <ul id="id_type">
    <li><label for="id_type_0"><input type="radio" name="type" value="inc" required="" id="id_type_0" checked="">
      Income</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="id_type_1"><input type="radio" name="type" value="exp" required="" id="id_type_1">
      Expense</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

...as you can see, the label wraps the radio input.

This is the selector I'm using:

```
.type input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

however having no success.

How can I overcome the issue?

I can't alter the HTML, it's generated by Django.

Answer (score 2):

```css
    .type input[type=radio]:checked+label {
        background-color: #e0e0e0;;
    }
```

```html
<div class="type">
    <ul id="id_type">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="inc" required="" id="id_type_0" checked="">
            <label for="id_type_0">Income</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="exp" required="" id="id_type_1">
            <label for="id_type_1">Expense</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your radio input inside of label. Check this;

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
 Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(elem){
 
   elem.addEventListener('change',function(a){

     Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(z){
     if(z.parentNode.classList.contains("yourClass")){
       z.parentNode.classList.remove("yourClass")
     }
     });
    
     a.target.parentNode.classList.add("yourClass");
   })
 });
```

```css
.yourClass{
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="type">
  <ul id="id_type">
    <li><label for="id_type_0"><input type="radio" name="type" value="inc" required="" id="id_type_0" checked="">
      Income</label>
    </li>
    <li><label for="id_type_1"><input type="radio" name="type" value="exp" required="" id="id_type_1">
      Expense</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't alter the HTML, it's generated by Django.